# Auto-wiring/injection of Individual beans of a type and bean of list of beans of a type in Spring Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have following set up in my spring configuration

```
@Bean
public Myclass myClassOne() {
    return new MyClass();
}

@Bean
public Myclass myClassTwo() {
    return new MyClass();
}

@Bean
public YourClass processAndCreateYourClass(List<MyClass> allMyclasses) {
    //Some business logic to process all myclasses beans so that I can create YourClass bean
     return new YourClass();
}
```

This works as expected and I get a list of all myclasses injected in `processAndCreateYourClass` (without autowired annotation)  BUT what If I have one more bean like following

```
@Bean
public List<Myclass> listOfMyClasses() {
    //return list of my classes from here
}
```

in `processAndCreateYourClass` method I was expecting union of all individually declared myclass beans and list returned by `listOfMyClasses`. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Is it fair to expect that behavior from Spring or there is better elegant solution for this?

Comment: do you need a bean of type `List<Myclass>` ? But you have it in `processAndCreateYourClass `. Could you please clarify? What is going to be the implementation of `listOfMyClasses ` ?

Comment: This is a wart due to legacy of how the Spring container handled things and the need for backwards compatibility. Explicitly providing a bean of any collection type tends to not work as desired and is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm.. i recommend to you use qualifiers to add your beans to the "processAndCreateYourClass".

Something like this will have maintainability and easy to read.

```
@Bean
public YourClass processAndCreateYourClass(@Qualifier("myClassOne") Myclass1, @Qualifier("myClassTwo") Myclass2) {
    //Some business logic to process all myclasses beans so that I can create YourClass bean
     return new YourClass();
}
```